# How to Capture events / Listen / Observe to events emitted from Inner functions in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

I would like to run a bunch of code within functions - and functions called within those functions and "bubble" the events up without too much work.

Note: I am trying to move away from OOP, more into functional programming so I can't use the class implements eventemitter. I am not sure if I have to

- expose event emitter from each object - or
- if I can just emit from one of the inner functions and monitor the event n the outer function - or
- even just pass the emitter through as a function parameter.

obj2.ts

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'events'

export async function obj2(){
    const ev = new EventEmitter()
    ev.emit('test','Yahoo!')
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
    ev.emit('test2','Yahoo! - second time')
    ev.emit('test','Yahoo!')
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    ev.emit('test2','Yahoo! - third time')
}
```

obj1.ts

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'events'
import { inherits } from 'util'
import {obj2} from './obj2'

async function obj1(){
     await obj2()    
}

inherits(obj1, EventEmitter)

export {obj1}
```

index.js ( entry point )

```
import {obj1} from './obj1'

obj1.on('test', () => { // << this doesn't work obviously 
    //console.log(this)
    console.log('**')
})

obj1()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd need `obj1` - you can just export the `EventEmitter` from `obj2` and listen on the returned object:

in obj2.js:

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'events'

export const obj2EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
export async function startEmitting(){
    obj2EventEmitter.emit('test','Yahoo!')
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
    obj2EventEmitter.emit('test2','Yahoo! - second time')
    obj2EventEmitter.emit('test','Yahoo!')
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    obj2EventEmitter.emit('test2','Yahoo! - third time')
}
```

in your index.js:

```
import {obj2EventEmitter, startEmitting} from './obj2';

obj2EventEmitter.on('test', () => {
    console.log('**')
});

(async () => {
    await startEmitting();
})()
```

Comment: Its a concept - that's why I wanted obj1 - it was to see if I needed to have an event emitter object in all places I was emitting events right up to the surface

Comment: Well you need to pass up the emitter object in order to be able to attach to it. Alternatively you can provide an interface to attach to it. E.g. you could create a function in the `obj1` module that takes an event name and a callback and delegates to the emitter object. Does this answer your question?